# Error writing text into a .txt file in python

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I am making a program that will 
1. Create a text file
2. Allow a password to be stored
3. Allow a password to be changed
4. Add an additional password
5. Delete a specific password
The problem is in `def delete():`. I put in three passwords on three seperate lines: first, second, third. When I choose to delete password "second", it reprints the list from before, and then prints the new list at the end of the last password.

Here is my code:

```
import time
def create():
    file = open("password.txt", "w")
    passwordOfChoice = input("The password you want to store is: ")
    file.write(passwordOfChoice)
    print ("Your password is: ", passwordOfChoice)
    file.close()
    time.sleep(2)
def view():
    file = open("password.txt","r")
    print ("Your password is: ",
           "\n", file.read())
    file.close()
    time.sleep(2)
def change():
    file = open("password.txt", "w")
    newPassword = input("Please enter the updated password: ")
    file.write(newPassword)
    print ("Your new password is: ", newPassword)
    file.close()
    time.sleep(2)
def add():
    file = open("password.txt", "a")
    extraPassword = input("The password you want to add to storage is: ")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write(extraPassword)
    print ("The password you just stored is: ", extraPassword)
    file.close()
    time.sleep(2)
def delete():
    phrase = input("Enter a password you wish to remove: ")

    f = open("password.txt", "r+")
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if line != phrase+"\n":
            f.write(line)
    f.close()

print("Are you trying to: ",
      "\n1. Create a password?",
      "\n2. View a password?",
      "\n3. Change a previous password?",
      "\n4. Add a password?",
      "\n5. Delete a password?",
      "\n6. Exit?\n")
function = input()
print("")

if (function == '1'):
    create()
elif (function == '2'):
    view()
elif (function == '3'):
    change()
elif (function == '4'):
    add()
elif (function == '5'):
    delete()
elif (function == '6'):
    print("Understood.", "\nProgram shutting down.")
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("Your answer was not valid.")
    print("Program shutting down...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

To show what I meant above, here is my output:

```
Your password is:
 first
second
thirdfirst
third
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix my `def delete():` function so that it will not rewrite the original data? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the 'r+' mode. When you use 'r+' you can read and write, sure, but it's up to you to control *where* in the file you write.
What's happening is you read the file, and the cursor is stuck at the end, so when you write it back, Python dutifully puts your new lines on the end of the file.
See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) about file methods; you're looking for something like **seek**.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do ypu know how to get rid of the first second third, so that the end output for that example would only say "first" and "third"

Comment: I have completed the code. It now allows deletions, changes, creations, and viewings. Thank you for your help in the process!

Comment: No problem. Was unable to use SO for the past couple of days, glad to hear you solved the trouble!

Comment: Thank you for your help and now that you are able to use SO, thank you for helping me! Have an excellent day.